# How to wait for the end of the loading of a webpage before resuming execution using cefshrap (C#)

Tags: c#, cefsharp, webautomation

I'm currently working with CefSharp on a web application. I would like to be able to pause the execution of the program while the webpage is loading and then, once all the elements have been loaded, resume the execution (for example click on a button or enter a given field).

I'm a former java developper and have used Selenium on a few projects. I know that what I'm looking for is a CefSharp equivalent to the "driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(...);" method of Selenium. I've been looking for a solution for a while and have found a few threads speaking of this problem however none of the solutions seems to work.

Comment: If you haven't already please read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#handlers and  https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#javascript-integration also please include references and examples of what you have tried already. You can enable remote debugging and use puppeteer or selenium.